# Flatten only first layer of array

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I worked very hard on creating my own flatten function using functional programming. I have it all working except for some reason false is not being included in the answer. I am trying to input it as an answer on [codewars](http://www.codewars.com/) and it works for all cases except this:

```
flatten([[[1,2,3]]]) // => [[1,2,3]]
```

Instead, my code is outputting:

```
flatten([[[1,2,3]]]) // => [1,2,3]
```

The frustrating part about this is that I think **my answer makes more sense** than the default one provided. But in any case I still want to solve this problem. The challenge I am facing is that I have built something so complex it is difficult to modify without disrupting the entire structure and needing to entire refactor everything. I want to create a function for special cases like the one above but not sure how to do it without disrupting my current structure. How can I implement this method?

All the other threads on this type of thing deal with numpy, I can't find anything relevant to Javascript. Kthnx

**Sexy code:**

```
var flatten = function (parentArray) {
return reduce(pushArray,[],parentArray);
}

function reduce(combine, base, array) {
  forEach(array, function(element) {
    base = combine(base,element);
  });
  return base;
}

function pushArray(baseArray,tempArray) {
  while (tempArray[0]) {
  baseArray.push(tempArray.shift()); }
return baseArray;
}
```

Comment: Where is *forEach* defined?

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment, but I needed space:

Assuming the *forEach* function is something like:

```
function forEach(arr, fn) {
  for (var i=0, iLen=arr.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    if (arr.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      fn(arr[i], i, arr);
    }
  }
}
```

then:

```
flatten([[[1,2,3]]]) // => [[1,2,3]]
```

which seems to be what you want. Or have I misread the question?